# The future and present value of an annuity of $100 payable at the start of each quarter for 15 yrs if the rate is 12% compounded quarterly is?

Tags: arithmetic, finance

What are the future and present value of an annuity of $100 payable at 
the beginning of each quarter for 15 years if the interest rate is 12% 
compounded quarterly?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

The future value is

$FV=100\cdot q \cdot \frac{q^{60}-1}{q-1}$ with $q=1+\frac{0.12}{4}=1+0.03$

The present value is $PV=\frac{FV}{q^{60}}$

Comment: Nice. You´re welcome.